# Confused where to look for @pnp full documentation

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, documentation, pnp-js

I'm honestly confused where to find the full documentation of the JavaScript @pnp documentation.
According to Microsoft's docs, it's supposed to be at [pnp/js](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/).

However, I feel the docs are incomplete:

Let's say you want to look at how to get a row of a SharePoint List filtering the results. I see the docs for that are in https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/docs/items/ but there are only examples and such...

Also, there are some pages of the docs that can only be accessed through the search box...

Where are the full docs? What options can I give to those calls appart from what I can deduce from the examples?